# Performance difference between SELECT sum(coloumn_name) FROM and SELECT coloumn_name in CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

I like to know the performance difference in executing the following two queries for a table cycling.cyclist_points containing 1000s of rows. :

```
SELECT sum(race_points)
FROM cycling.cyclist_points
WHERE id = e3b19ec4-774a-4d1c-9e5a-decec1e30aac;

select *
from cycling.cyclist_points
WHERE id = e3b19ec4-774a-4d1c-9e5a-decec1e30aac;
```

If sum(race_points) causes the query to be expensive, I will have to look for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Performance Difference between your query :**

- Both of your query need to scan same number of row.(Number of row in that partition)
- First query only selecting a single column, so it is little bit faster.

**Instead of calculating the sum run time, try to preprocess the sum.**

If `race_points` is int or bigint then use a counter table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE race_points_counter (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    sum counter
);
```

Whenever a new data inserted into `cyclist_points` also increment the sum with your current point.

```
UPDATE race_points_counter SET sum = sum + ? WHERE id = ?
```

Now you can just select the sum of that id

```
SELECT sum FROM race_points_counter WHERE id = ?
```